# how to change the state of a job in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am making a script that handles multiple jobs. The script that controls the jobs does different things with the jobs depending on its state.

For example if I call the `get-job` command I get this...

```
    Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
80     Job80           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...                      
82     Job82           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...                      
84     Job84           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...                      
86     Job86           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...                      
88     Job88           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...                      
90     Job90           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...
```

How can I make it so that the jobs, when an specific error occurs will return a state of "Failure"?

Comment: `Start-Job { throw } | Wait-Job`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to put a throw statement in the slave scripts